# Cannot create new live template in RubyMine7.1.4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, intellij-idea, rubymine, live-templates

I'm using rubymine 7.1.4 and I found that I could not create new live template. I tried to create the live template with the following steps
1. Go to Preferences -> Editors -> Live template
2. I select the "user" group and click the "+" icon in the top-right corner, then select "1. Live template"
3. I fill in the "Abbreviation" field with `mmfd` and "Description field with "method_missing for decorators", then the "Template text" field with

```
  def method_missing?(method_name, *args, &block)
    @tweet.send(method_name, *args, &block)
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private=false)
    @tweet.respond_to?(method_name, include_private=false) || super
  end
```

4. I click the "Define" and select Ruby as the context. Then I click the OK button.
   Then I went to a ruby file editor and type the abbreviation "mmfd", and nothing happened. 
   I reopen the "live template" preference page and the template I created was gone.
   I also tried select the code in the editor and then perform "Save as live template", fill in the abbreviation, and this way does not work neither.

Comment: How exactly do you create the template?

Comment: @yole I updated my question with the steps I tried to create the live template.